# Why Register GIT Repository disabled in Botium-Box community edition?

Tags: dialogflow-es

In my Botium-Box community login I am not able to add my Git repository test  cases.Is that any configuration need to be enabled or It is not available in Botium-Box community ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test Case Versioning is a Botium Box Professional/Enterprise feature - see [here](http://www.botium.at/pricing.html) for details.

EDIT: You can use a shared folder to hold your test cases, and you can then in turn add this shared folder to git.